# Inside of a Stored Procedure, testing whether a SQL Server user exists, and whether their password is valid

Tags: sql-server

I need create a SQL Server stored procedure that does the following:

1. Take an database user name and password as parameters.
2. If the user does not exist or the password is invalid, return an empty rowset.
3. Else, perform a query and return its result.

I don't know how do perform step 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two routes to go with this:

1) Query the SQL Server tables directly to find a match. You'll probably have to go through a view, instead of accessing the table directly. Maybe, select * from Sys.sql_logins

Need to find a way to hash the password, to compare against the hashed version, in Sys.sql_logins.password_hash

As of SQL Server 2008, they added the function PWDCOMPARE(). That's clearly the way MS intended for this to be solved.

So, in 2008, I would think you'd query it as 
select * from Sys.sql_logins where name = 'login' and PWDCOMPARE('password', Sys.sql_logins.password_hash) = 1

Oddly enough, I just tried this on SQL 2005, and the function seems to exist.

2) Attempt a connection to the SQL server via a call to OPENDATASOURCE () and test for failure. MSDN page for OPENDATASOURCE() is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276845(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: I can find whether the user exists by querying `sys.sysusers`, but how do I test whether the password is valid?

Comment: I don't think you want to compare against users -- they are db-specific. You're more likely interested at syslogins.

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is the following, connect to the DB specifying an user "A", and, from that connection, test whether another user "B" exists in the same DB, and whether his password is "X". User "B" need not be logged in.

Comment: Are you sure that you really mean user? Users are simply the set of privileges that a particular login has against a database. A login will have a user for each database that the login can access data in. When you are talking about a 'password' to connect with, that password belongs to the login, not the user.

Comment: What I meant is I want to test whether user "B" can connect with password "X", but I don't actually want to connect as "B".

Answer (score 1):

Why not let SQL Server do this for you. That's what the built-in security scheme is for, after all. Simply grant permissions to the user (or role) to the stored procedure(s) that contains the query for the data. Then, in the application calling the SP, you'll open a connection to the DB with that user's login credentials. If the user is invalid, they can't connect and you can catch the exception. If the user is valid in the DB but does not have permissions to the stored procedure, you can catch the exception.

Comment: Actually, the user won't connect to the DB directly. I have a Web app that consumes a Web Service, which in turn connects to the database. I don't want the Web Service to be able to do all that the user can do directly.